# Function to return proper name casing using JavaScript and Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a function  that correct the name input, so if the user entrs: mohamed ahmed the output will be Mohamed Ahmed.

I added this filter:

```
app.filter('properName', function () {
    return function (x) {
        var newName = '';
        newName += x[0].toUpperCase();
        for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] == ' ') {
                newName += ' ';
                newName += x[i + 1].toUpperCase();
            }
            else {
                newName += x[i].toLowerCase();
            }
        }
        return newName;
    }
});
```

but when I enter any input the letter after space is duplicated; one upper cased and the other is lower:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).filter('properName', function () {
    return function (x) {
        var newName = '';
        newName += x[0].toUpperCase();
        for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] == ' ') {
                newName += ' ';
                newName += x[i + 1].toUpperCase();
            }
            else {
                newName += x[i].toLowerCase();
            }
        }
        return newName;
    }
});;
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
   
           PN: <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-bind="n"/>
           Proper Name: <h3 ng-bind="name | properName"></h3>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (x[i] == ' ') {
   newName += ' ';
   newName += x[i + 1].toUpperCase();
}
```

To

```
if(i && x[i-1] ==' ' ){
  newName += x[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

When `x[i]` is the space it can be lowercased with no problem. You don't want to make adjustment until you actually get to the character after the space

Comment: in `(i && x[i-1] ==' ' )` what's the boolean value of `i`?

Comment: actually don't need the `i &&` since you start loop at `1`. I wrote that to make sure `i` wasn't `0` without fully reading the code

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: 0 and 1 are the only numbers to have boolean values: 1 is true and 0 is false, right?

Comment: No... `if(5)` would be truthy. With numbers...any positive non zero is truthy

Answer (score 2):

as in pure js:

```
function toFullName(name) {
    return (name || '')
        .split(' ')
        .map(function (t) {
            return (t[0] || '').toUpperCase() + (t.substr(1) || '').toLowerCase();
        }).join(' ');
}

toFullName('mohamed ahmed');
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlfow. 

Please explain a little more clearly what it is that the code is doing.... example:   `you can use the split function to separate the word boundaries, followed by the map function to loop through the array and the substr() function with the first character of parameter "t"    etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).filter('properName', function () {
    return function (x) {
        var newName = x.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(i =>i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substring(1)).join(' ')
       return newName;
    }
});;
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
   
           PN: <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-bind="n"/>
           Proper Name: <h3 ng-bind="name | properName"></h3>

</div>
```